# How to push Maven artifact to Nexus through GitLab CI

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, nexus

I am new to GitLab and Nexus. I am trying to create artifact and push it to Nexus repo. I am getting error while running a job. Could anyone please help.

`[ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: /builds/<project path>.m2/settings.xml`

Build is executing successfully. Failing in test stage. Also added Nexus `URL`, `Username` and `Password` in gitlab `Variables`.

Is there a way to move settings.xml to GitLab?

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8 

variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
   MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
cache: 
  paths:
   - .m2/repository/
   - target/

stages:
   - build
   - test
   - package
   - deploy

build:
    stage: build 
    script:   
      - mvn compile 

test:
    stage: test 
    script: 
       - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test 
       - echo "The code has been tested" 

package:
    stage: package 
    script: 
       - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
       - echo "Packaging the code" 
    artifacts: 
       paths: 
        - target/*.war 
    only: 
       - master 

deploy:
    stage: deploy 
    script: 
       - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
       - echo "installing the package in local repository" 
    only: 
      - master
```

**pom**

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<server>
  <id>nexus-releases</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>pass</password>
</server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>central</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: First it does not make sense to separate `compile`, `package` and `deploy` cause you are running several parts several times. A simple `mvn deploy` will reduce build time cause you seemed to misunderstood the maven life cycle model. Apart from that the error message tells you that the `settings.xml` is not located where you expect it be...

Comment: Yea. I will reduce the code. How do I load the settings.xml to that directory. I cannot find it in GitLab.

Comment: You don't need to put the `settings.xml` file to that location you can locate the `settings.xml` whereever you like if you correctly define it via `mvn -s <path>/settings.xml ..` ...

Comment: It will not reduce the code which is not the issue it will drop your build time...for the whole pipeline ...